# Is it possible to have multiple receivers inside elements.xml?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I have a feature for a site APC and it has event handlers for custom lists, which is working perfectly.
Now I want to add event handlers for my announcements within the same site. Can I add it inside the elements.xml as a second receivers node having listtemplateid=104??

Thanks in advance.
janejanejane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elements.xml file can have definitions for multiple receivers.

But simply editing the file or redeploying the feature will not add the event receivers to a site that has already activated the feature. You will probably need to deactivate and reactivate the feature in that site. I am not sure that even upgrading the feature or doing a force activate (without a deactivate) will be enough for the changes to take effect.

Comment: hi rich, it didn't work for me. i deactivated the feature then reactivated it again after building and deploying everything. i am confused because the node definition for my announcements has the same structure as that for my custom list events. any idea on this?

Comment: ooops, my bad. i didn't have breakpoints in the code. :D sorry.

Comment: to let SharePoint use new event receiver you have to restart SP Timer service (SPTimerV4).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely you can. Its supported by sharepoint.